# How does unit testing on the iPhone work?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, uikit

Do I need special libraries for this, or can I just create a huge class that trys to instantiate every object of my project and test all the methods in there? How's that done in theory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're targeting iPhone OS 2.2 or later, you can use the version of OCUnit that's bundled with Xcode.  There's [a good blog article](http://www.mobileorchard.com/ocunit-integrated-unit-testing-in-xcode/) by Kailoa Kadano about this on Mobile Orchard.  OCUnit is a unit testing framework that's similar to the well known JUnit framework from the Java world.

You can always do "poor man's unit testing" by creating a simple test program that uses the `assert()` macro in the C header `assert.h` or the `NSAssert()` macros in Cocoa/Cocoa-touch.  That's not a horrible way to get started doing unit testing, but I'd really recommend looking at OCUnit or another unit testing framework eventually.

Which ever way you structure your unit tests, you'll want to create a separate target in your Xcode project to build and run the tests.

Answer (score 6):

Googling "unit testing iPhone" gives [this excellent link](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting) as the first hit:

To sum up, Google Toolbox provides a good infrastructure for unit testing on iPhone.

Comment: I use GTM for all my iPhone unit testing.  He may also wish to read http://developer.apple.com/tools/unittest.html , which explains the philosophy behind OCUnit and unit tests in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

[GHUnit](http://rel.me/2009/02/21/unit-testing-for-mac-os-x-and-iphone-ghunit/) is awesome.

Comment: What are extra features of GHUnit compared to GoogleToolBox framework?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I really love [Kiwi](http://www.kiwi-lib.info/): BDD (RSpec) for iPhone & iPad.

For a comprehensive answer, check out
[iOS Tests/Specs TDD/BDD and Integration & Acceptance Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114083/ios-tests-specs-tdd-bdd-and-integration-acceptance-testing).