# iPhone BDD testing/iCuke advice

Tags: iphone, cucumber, automated-tests, bdd

I have been recently introduced to the concept of BDD and am using SpecFlow on a web system I am working on.  I would like to use BDD with a side project I am working on in my spare time, creating an iPhone application.

After reading articles on the net and question: [iOS Tests/Specs TDD/BDD and Integration & Acceptance Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114083/iphone-testing-tdd-bdd) I have decided to look into iCuke this weekend as it seems the best option avaiable to me, however it appears that the project isn't currently being maintained?

My question is does anyone know if the project is still being maintained?  If not is it currently at a stable and useful release?  Or does anyone know of any other forks that are being maintained?  E.g. I found this blog post ([cucumber-tests-on-iphoneipad](http://blog.jayway.com/2011/02/11/cucumber-tests-on-iphoneipad)) just wondering if anyone there were any more out there that might offer more functionality or regular updates that I should use before looking into iCuke this weekend.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was recently looking into this same thing. I contacted the main author of icuke and a few of the fork authors. For the most part, they don't have time to maintain it so I don't see the projects progressing much unless someone really takes it over. For this reason, I've been messing with a newer addition to the acceptance testing frameworks, [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank).
Frank has been working excellent for me so far and is being actively maintained. Feedback on the Google Group has been awesome also.

Hope that helps!