# Frank: Is it possible to write step definitions in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cucumber

1. How could I write step definitions in Objective-C? E.g.:

   ```
   Given(@"^the address book is empty$", ^{
       ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
       CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
       for (int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
           ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressBook,
                   CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i), NULL);
       }
   });
   ```

   The example above was derived from [Rob Holland's blog post "BDD on iPhone: iCuke"](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2010-07/bdd-on-iphone-icuke).

   Why would I want to do such a thing? Because, as much as I love Ruby, I prefer to develop iOS apps in Objective-C and to write tests in the same language as that of the app I'm testing. Also, this would allow me to do low-level things, like erasing the address book or editing other data with Core Data.
2. Can I name the `features` directory `Features` with a capital "F"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I responded to Matt's question on the Frank mailing list [here](http://groups.google.com/group/frank-discuss/browse_frm/thread/89cc53b217c5242a)

Answer (score 1):

I agree; test your Objective-C applications in Objective-C.  Personally, I use Cedar for this and would do it soup-to-nuts in Objective-C (no cuke), but I realize that might not be a very helpful answer.  Not to hijack your thread, but did you find Frank to be any easier than Cedar to set up?

Comment: Frank and Cedar are really intended for quite different things. Cedar is focused on unit testing, at the level of individual methods in your classes. Frank is focussed on functional/acceptance testing, at the level of end-to-end UI functionality.

Comment: Why no Cuke? I haven't tried Frank yet, but skimming the instructions, I think it's easier to set up than Cedar. iCuke was a one-command install (icuke) and worked great, but development has dwindled, and I got an error trying to install it on Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Actually, Frank was about just as difficult as Cedar for me to set up. [I'm going to try out UIAutomation for acceptance tests and just leave testing the lower-level Objective-C stuff to Cedar unit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114083/ios-tests-specs-tdd-bdd-and-integration-acceptance-testing).

Answer (score 1):

To attempt to answer your second question:

By default I think Cucumber looks for a 'features' directory. I don't know if it is case sensitive, but the fact that your asking means it probably is. You can specify the directory when you run Cucumber.

eg. a cucumber target in my Rakefile with non-standard location

```
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = ["--format pretty", "FunctionalTests/Frank"]
end
```

Comment: Or you can just add the path to your cucumber command: `cucumber Features/`