# SenTestingKit (integrated with XCode) versus GHUnit on XCode 4 for Unit Testing?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, tdd, xcode4

Any advice on which way to go regarding Unit Testing on XCode 4 out of SenTestingKit (the inbuild unit testing framework with XCode 4) and GHUnit?  In particular:

- With the apparent improvements to Unit Testing in XCode 4 does this mean there are no major benefits of running with GHUnit?
- Alternatively are there some integration benefits that make a smooth development process that could be achieved using XCode's unit testing framework (SenTestingKit) as opposed to GHUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually got some good feedback after also polling the apple forum community here https://devforums.apple.com/message/408448#408448

Answer (score 5):

Greg, I answered your question on my blog, about 2 weeks late :).  The conclusion I came to is the GHUnit isn't obsolete, but you should use SenTestingKit for new projects on Xcode 4.

http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/04/15/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-use-ocunit-and-sentest-instead-of-ghunit/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have in depth knowledge of both the Testings, One thing I read about is you can subclass GHUnit to use SenTest or GTMTestCase. [Read This](http://allseeing-i.com/GHUnit_nicer_unit_testing_with_Xcode). I guess you can write both the test cases using GHUnit and having UI makes it real simple and fun to use.