# Program for testing IOS app before submission?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, submission

i'm looking for a program that can simulates some clicks everywhere, on every button and stuff in my iphone app, to find some crashs before submitting the app.

i don't know if something like that really exist.
Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 4, Apple started supplying the UIAutomation framework that allows you to test your app automatically. It leverages Accessibility.

[Blog examples](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation)

[Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try out [fonemonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/fonemonkey).

You can create your scripts programatically or record movements and clicks on the screen like Selenium style.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the [Telerik Test Studio for iOS](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing/ios-application-testing.aspx). I haven't tried it yet, but it seems promising.

Comment: looks cool, but i don't want to record click and stuff, just a program that will click everywhere is possible to see if there is a probleme somewhere

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is likely to be an Acceptance Test framework.
I don't know any of them that can automatically recognize the UIControls in you app and perform random actions, but you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114083/ios-tests-specs-tdd-bdd-and-integration-acceptance-testing) to have an overview of the available technologies to perform UI automated tests (in the section Acceptance Test).